# Getting "java.io.IOException: Stream closed", when trying to read file from relative path

Tags: java, yaml, fileinputstream, snakeyaml

I am trying to read yaml file. At first i had absolute path,it was working fine. Now when i have war file to be deployed in server,i want to change the absolute to relative path. From then it is giving the error.
Code:

```
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/config/jobnames.yml");
    HashMap yamlMap = yaml.load(inputStream);
```

stack of exception:

```
org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.update(StreamReader.java:218)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.ensureEnoughData(StreamReader.java:176)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.ensureEnoughData(StreamReader.java:171)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.reader.StreamReader.peek(StreamReader.java:126)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.scanToNextToken(ScannerImpl.java:1177)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:287)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:227)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseImplicitDocumentStart.produce(ParserImpl.java:195)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:148)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:107)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:141)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:525)
org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:453)
```

please help me out what is the issue? Thanks

Comment: Can you try this `InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/jobnames.yml");` instead of using full path to file use relative path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a `ClassLoader`, the path should be relative and not absolute, as `resources` is directly available on the classpath (Also getting ClassLoader is missing in your code)

Can you try this instead of using absolute path-

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/jobnames.yml");
HashMap yamlMap = yaml.load(inputStream);
```

That should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() loads resources from the classpath as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-

So you have to omit "src/main/resources" since this just happens to be your project setup path. "/config/jobnames.yml" should work.